# Difference between CanCanCan "index" rule with and without a block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan, cancancan

Are these two statements basically the same? If they aren't then what should the second version look like?  And what's going on under the covers?

```rb
can :index, User, approved: true

can :index, User do |user|
  user.approved?
end
```

I'm not able to get "block" versions of tests working.  Everything else works fine.. but blocks don't work.  I'm clearly doing something wrong, so I'm trying to understand.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rules with blocks are used when an instance is passed to the rule:

```
can?(:show, User.first)
```

The `index` action is special because there's no instance of User to pass to the rule, you are not loading a specific user, but multiple.

So,

```
can :index, User, approved: true
```

When the `UserController#index` action is hit, assuming you have `load_and_authorize_resource` (or similar in place), it will load in `@users` all the users with `approved: true`. If there are no conditions, all users will be loaded. It's straightforward.

Now,

```
can :index, User do |user|
  user.approved?
end
```

If a rule has a block and the instance is not passed to it (as I said above), the rule will always return `true` as in **authorized**,  **BUT** no users will be loaded.

More explanations, [here.](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/develop/docs/define_abilities_with_blocks.md#define-abilities-with-blocks)

Comment: Thank you!!!  This makes perfect sense and is what I am seeing but I just hadn't connected the :index thing vs instances.

Answer (score 1):

https://gitlab.quints.io/quints/bi_backend/-/blob/pre_production/app/models/payment_system/bank_transfer_requisite.rb#L61

> Note that if you pass a block to a can or cannot, the block only executes if an instance of a class is passed to can? or cannot? calls.

> If you define a can or cannot with a block and an object is not passed, the check will pass.

Maybe this is answer ?